# transform tolerance

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, All,

I am getting TF transform error.
my setup is two laser, one SICK LM100 for AMCL. one Hokuyo URG for local cost map.
the move_base Local cost map is dropping packages and complains old data.

```
Transform [sender=/hokuyo_scan]
For frame [local_laser]: No transform to fixed frame [world]. TF error: [Lookup would require extrapolation into the future. Requested time 1407940054.418783996 but the latest data is at time 1407940054.271341707, when looking up transform from frame [local_laser] to frame [world]]
```

I found there's a transform_tolerance setting in  costmap_2d package, and I believe it's been set more than enough >1.0s.
the error still persists.

however, when I use either single laser for both purposes, there isn't such problem.

anyone share a light?

thanks.

ray

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190052/transform-tolerance/) by [dreamcase](https://answers.ros.org/users/18446/dreamcase/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2014-08-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-13**:
Does this happen once or all the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The transform tolerance parameter in costmap_2d doesn't get used everywhere you'd expect. Try setting the transform tolerance in amcl instead, which post-dates the localization transform, making them valid slightly longer into the future. Just not 1 s, it should only need to be high enough to cover the lag in the system.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0